# Compare two strings and get the difference

Tags: c#

How can i compare two strings in c# and gets the difference?

for example:

String1 :  i have a car

string2 :  i have a new car bmw

result: new, bmw

Comment: Can we assume you want it split by word boundary?

Comment: What about the spaces between "new" and "car" and between "car" and "bmw"? Do you need to know that one of the words occured before "car" and the other one after? What about the differences between "i have a car that is new" and "i have a new car"? is "new" a difference here as well? What about deletions? "i have a new car" vs. "i have a car"? Do you want to know that "new" + a space was removed? In short, you need to tell us some of your assumptions or limits to your problem.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsenno, in that case the difference is "that", "is"

@ChaosPandion, i think yes :p. i dont know how can i do this :S

Comment: What if a word occurs more than once? "i have a car i have" vs. "i have a car"?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsenno, the space dont matter, only the words. Thats my question, how can i compare?, because its gonna be a phrase, and can contain repetitions

Comment: so spaces, order, and multiple occurances does not matter? Then I think ChaosPandion's answer below is exactly what you want.

Comment: i want repetitions and words. the order and spaces dont matter

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to make sure the larger set is on the left hand side of the `Except` (not sure if there is a pure Linq way to achieve that):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "i have a car a car";
        string s2 = "i have a new car bmw";

        List<string> diff;
        IEnumerable<string> set1 = s1.Split(' ').Distinct();
        IEnumerable<string> set2 = s2.Split(' ').Distinct();

        if (set2.Count() > set1.Count())
        {
            diff = set2.Except(set1).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            diff = set1.Except(set2).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe some references. what reference do you have?

Comment: default refs in a new console project under VS 2008

Answer (score 12):

Based off your question *(It is a bit vague.)* this should work.

```
var first = string1.Split(' ');
var second = string2.Split(' ');
var primary = first.Length > second.Length ? first : second;
var secondary = primary == second ? first : second;
var difference = primary.Except(secondary).ToArray();
```

At the top of your file make sure you include:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: this would make these two strings identical: "i have a car" and "car a i have". But yes, uncertain whether that is OK with the OP.

Comment: this works with repetitions?
for example "i have a car i have" vs. "i have a car"

Comment: returns no results if smaller set on left side

Answer (score 9):

You can use a difference algorithm for this task. The paper "[An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.6927&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" describes a quite powerful algorithm to accomplish this task. For an implementation in C#, you can have a look at "[An O(ND) Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DiffAlgorithmCS.aspx)", but IMHO it surely is more interesting to have a look at the paper and implement it for yourself in case you're interested on how the algorithm works in detail.

Answer (score 2):

I had some null point exception with null strings so I improved Mitch Wheat answer to handle this problem too:

```cs
public static string Difference(string str1, string str2)
{
    if (str1 == null)
    {
        return str2;
    }
    if (str2 == null)
    {
        return str1;
    }
    
    List<string> set1 = str1.Split(' ').Distinct().ToList();
    List<string> set2 = str2.Split(' ').Distinct().ToList();

    var diff = set2.Count() > set1.Count() ? set2.Except(set1).ToList() : set1.Except(set2).ToList();

    return string.Join("", diff);
}
```

Comment: This also gives an exception in some cases, namely if both are null, since you don't check 2 if 1 is null and vice versa.