# How can you get the non-intersected portion of two lists of strings?

Tags: c#

I have two lists of strings, illustrated as comma-separated below.  How can I get the inverse of the intersection (i.e. all items that are only in one or the other list but not both?

For example:

```
string test1 = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
string test2 = "word2,word4";
```

In this example, I am looking for "word1" and "word3" since they each only occur in one list.

Comment: Please define this difference operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343874/compare-two-strings-and-get-the-difference

Comment: I need to find out that "word1,word3" does not match what was in test1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void test()
    {
        string test1 = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
        string test2 = "word2,word4";

        List<string> test1list = test1.Split(',').ToList();
        List<string> test2Lists = test2.Split(',').ToList();
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in test1list)
        {
            if (!test2Lists.Contains(item))
            {
                if (result.Any())
                {
                    result.Add(","  +item );
                }
                else
                {
                    result.Add(item);
                }

            }
        }

        result.ForEach(p => Console.Write(p));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: can you change your code snippet so that it outputs onto the same line and not a line each for each word? @jophy job

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock this just sounds like you're asking for him to write your code for you

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 10):

```
string test1 = "word1,word2,word3,word4";
string test2 = "word2,word4";
var result = string.Join(",", test1.Split(',').Except(test2.Split(',')));
```

Comment: I don't think that would work if `test2` also contains unique elements. I would suggest something like that instead: `var result = string.Join(",", (test1 + "," + test2).Split(',').GroupBy(w => w).Where(group => group.Count() == 1).Select(group => group.Key));`

Comment: This only works if we can expect the differences to be "words" split by commas, but since the OP isnt clear and i was going to suggest this myself, good job.

Comment: @TheNewGuyOnTheRock Is all you can say *"this doesn't work"*? Of course it works. Just copy and paste above code and test it. If you have other conditions, or compile time errors or runtime exceptions, include them in your post. See the section  [… is not working (properly).](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2014/10/missing-stackoverflow-topic-terrible-question/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop and check whether the string value present in another; something like

```
        string[] test1 = "word1,word2,word3,word4".Split(',');
        string[] test2 = "word2,word4".Split(',');

        foreach (var item in test1)
        {
            if (!test2.Contains(item))
                Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```