# compare List with different size in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have an application in C# .NET where a person can submit an abstract. It will be a paragraph.

Now if I made any changes on that abstract from my end, It should send the email to that person with the Original abstract and modified abstract. Where in Modified section it should highlight the changes done.

I have written a function for this:

```
   public string[] compareText(string submittedValue,string updatedValue) 
    {
        #region COMPARETEXT

        List<string> oldAbstract = submittedValue.Split('.').ToList<string>();
        List<string> newAbstract = updatedValue.Split('.').ToList<string>();
        string resultOldAbstract = "";
        string resultNewAbstract = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < (oldAbstract.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            if (String.Equals(oldAbstract[i], newAbstract[i], StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {

                resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract[i].ToString() + ".";

                resultNewAbstract += newAbstract[i].ToString() + ".";
            }

            else
            {

                List<string> oldAbstract1 = oldAbstract[i].Split(' ').ToList<string>();
                List<string> newAbstract1 = newAbstract[i].Split(' ').ToList<string>();
                if (oldAbstract1.Count == newAbstract1.Count)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < (oldAbstract1.Count); j++)
                    {
                        if (String.Equals(oldAbstract1[j], newAbstract1[j], StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        {
                            if (j < (oldAbstract1.Count - 1))
                            {
                                resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract1[j].ToString() + " ";

                                resultNewAbstract += newAbstract1[j].ToString() + " ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract1[j].ToString() + ".";

                                resultNewAbstract += newAbstract1[j].ToString() + ".";
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            if (j < (oldAbstract1.Count - 1))
                            {
                                resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract1[j].ToString() + " ";
                                resultNewAbstract += "<span style='background:yellow'>" + newAbstract1[j].ToString() + "</span> ";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract1[j].ToString() + ".";
                                resultNewAbstract += "<span style='background:yellow'>" + newAbstract1[j].ToString() + "</span>.";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    resultOldAbstract += oldAbstract[i].ToString() + ".";
                    resultNewAbstract += "<span style='background:yellow'>" + newAbstract[i].ToString() + "</span>.";
                }

            }

        }

        //return resultOldAbstract,resultNewAbstract;
        return new[] {resultOldAbstract,resultNewAbstract};

        #endregion
    }
```

but it only works when the size of both list are same. For e.g.

```
****Submitted abstract****

   hi This is John. i am 26 year old. I live in New York.


****Updated abstract****
  Hi This is John. I am 26 year old. I live in washington.
```

when I do these changes then It works fine. It highlights the changes done at *hi*, *i*, *New York*.

Here the submitted list and updated list both have same number of elements ( here it is 3 , bcz i am splitting at fullstop '.'). But suppose in my update abstract I add a new line or remove a line:

```
****Updated abstract****
  Hi This is John. I am 26 year old. I live in washington. I am a software engineer.

       or

****Updated abstract****
  Hi This is John. I am 26 year old.
```

then it does not work because the size of list is different and in for loop it throws index error.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343874/compare-two-strings-and-get-the-difference

Comment: What if your input has a period inside of the sentence?  `This document is from Dr. No.`

Comment: but that will not impact the result because it will only Add one more element in the list