# how to identify difference between two strings appearing same in naked eyes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, entity-framework-6

String looks same in naked eyes:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
   var peoples = from p in db.Peoples.Where(r =>  
                      r.Name.ToUpper().Replace(" ","").Contains(searchString.ToUpper().Replace(" ","")))
                        select p;
  return View(peoples);
}
```

I have also compared it with the solution in:
'''[Compare two strings and get the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343874/compare-two-strings-and-get-the-difference)'''
result is **123AJAYKUMARMOURYA**

When I copy the string from SQL Server the search is working fine, this is happening with only 1 Name, as per customer the data was recorded from other computer.

How to identity the diference?

Thanks in advance,
Raju

Comment: *What* is the difference? what makes those strings different from each other?

Comment: Do you need this once or do this more often? are the strings equal length?

Comment: @Guy everyting appearing same, the name is not getting search by one of my client when I copy the text from SQL Server and paste it then only it is get searched, I think there is differance in character encoding

Comment: @raju1208 this seems more like a convertion error or something in your application. If it works when you use it directly in a statement then it seems ok. Perhaps your app adds, removes or changes something in the string (i.e. culture -> special letters/numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you could do, is use the code below to print both of your strings as hex and compare them by value. Though this is only a solution if you would want to do this once or twice. (I know it is not elegant, but it will tell you the difference)

```
        string n = "mynewstring";
        string m = "myNewString";
        foreach (char c in n)
        {
            Console.Write(((int)c).ToString(("X")));
            Console.Write("-");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (char c in m)
        {
            Console.Write(((int)c).ToString(("X")));
            Console.Write("-");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Result 1) 414A4159A04B554D4152 2) 414A4159204B554D4152 from String 1)  AJAY KUMAR 2)  AJAY KUMAR the difference is in the Space between the two words

Comment: Well there you go!