# Is there a way to compare two strings in C# and get the differences only?

Tags: c#, string, text-processing

I am trying to compare two string in C# and get the differences between them i.e words which are not present in the other string ignoring cases and commas just focusing on the words. If one string contains two or multiple `the` and the second string has one `the`, it means this will be disregarded as it exists in both. Example I have two strings like below;

1. Cat meet's a dog
2. Cat meet's a dog and a bird

The difference between those two strings is `and bird` because it does not exist in the first one or vise versa and I want to get those two words `and bird` either in a List or a new string with spaces between them and in other words I want the words which are not present in the other string. Is there a way this can be done in C#?

Comment: Watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343874/compare-two-strings-and-get-the-difference

Comment: That's not a *comparison*. Have you tried comparing characters at the same positions? Or a `secondString.Replace(firstString,"")` ?

Comment: You might want to read up on [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). You'll see that there's at least 5 common definitions described there so you need to decide which of those is "the" difference you're seeking.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes I want to compare whole sub-strings and then get the differences between the two. All will be converted to lower cases then compare

Comment: You're right, I tried to get too fancy. `Contains`, `StartsWith`, `IndexOf` can be used to check if one string is a superset of another, then `Replace` or `Remove` can produce the difference.

Comment: @codeninja have you tried anything? Even just `string2.Replace(string1,"")` ? You can check if one string is part of another easily. You don't even need to convert to lowercase, all comparison methods accept a parameter to ignore case.

Comment: String comparison accept a [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-6.0) parameter that specifies how case and culture are handled. You can use one of the `xxxIgnoreCase` values to ignore case, eg `string2.Replace(string1,"",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter It will be the and a bird as a result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried splitting them and and using `distinct`

Comment: @TimSchmelter an array of the differences or a List.

Comment: @codeninja why split at all? That's not what your examples show. You should explain what you *actually* want to do. Strings don't have math operations like numbers. Nor is there any difference between letters and space unless you actually want to treat text as words and sentences. Text processing is *not* trivial

Comment: @TimSchmelter I found a similar post from the first comment. It solved the problem. Its returning the differences and ignoring commas and other similar characters just the words and from the example above its returning `and a bird`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used the first comment's answer and It also used split and compared and then returned the differences in a List

Comment: There are a bunch of textual difference tools, for things like version control systems. But they are usually intended for a operator to review the results and make sense of it. Without knowing the purpose it is difficult to give any meaningful answer.

Comment: @JonasH This was to simply check the differences in a string. In the future what If i have a large string simply a document text and I want to tell which words have been deleted or added by comparing it to the new one in such a way I will keep the first string in a variable and after edits I will then compare to see if additions or deletions have been made. How could this be approached? Like a change tracker

Comment: I would do it like most VCS:es do, call another program that is made for that exact purpose.

Comment: @codeninja you never said you want to ignore whitespace and commas, or that you only care about words. That's most definitely not `simply check the differences`. As for `which words have been deleted or added by comparing it to the new one` that has *nothing* to do with what you asked. It's actually a pretty complex problem if you don't want your code to take exponential time to work. You'd have to split sentences, convert each word to numbers so that each sentence becomes a vector of numbers, then try to compare the vectors. There are several algorithms for this, depending on what you want

Comment: BTW you still haven't explained what you want.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I got the answer I can easily find the differences. I was caring most about the words. Lets say I want to check if new words have been deleted or added how can I go about achieving this? I will start from where I am to look for a solution to do this. To track changes, addition and deletion

Comment: @codeninja so you do care about the order of the words. And multiples aren't discarded, otherwise `a` wouldn't be in `and a bird`. What about `And cat meets a dog`? Should that still produce `and a bird` ? Or do you only care about matching from the start (called a prefix match)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats a mistake on my end. In that case I want two words `and` and `bird`. Thanks for pointing that out. I want only the words which are unique in one string not present in the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using LINQ. You don't need the "ToList()" part, but you mentioned that as one form of output you'd want:

```
string str1 = "Cat meet's a dog";
string str2 = "Cat meet's a dog and a bird";
string[] str1Words = str1.ToLower().Split(' ');
string[] str2Words = str2.ToLower().Split(' ');
var uniqueWords = str2Words.Except(str1Words).Concat(str1Words.Except(str2Words)).ToList();

// Do whatever you want with uniqueWords instead
Console.WriteLine($"output: {String.Join(" ", uniqueWords)}");
```

Comment: This works because you know that `str1` is a subset of `str2`.  What if you can't make that assumption?

Comment: I added the Concat part to check the other way too, based on your good point. I could have sworn when I first read this that the description justified my original answer. But when I read it again, I'm not sure why I was under that impression. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a simple solution, hope it will help -

The main method is called 'Difference' it receive 2 strings to compare and return an object called StringDiff.
It runs 2 loops, first comparing between the two strings char by char and then adding the rest of the longer string.

The 'StringDiff' object is a class with 2 char lists that represnt the differences of each string.

In the main method i use String.join to convert the char lists to a string and print it.

```
  internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter first string");
                string firstString = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("enter second string");
                string secondString = Console.ReadLine();
                StringsDiff _stringsDiff = Difference(firstString, secondString);
                Console.WriteLine(
                $"fist string difference: {string.Join("", _stringsDiff._diffList1)} / second string difference: {string.Join("", _stringsDiff._diffList2)}");
                Console.WriteLine("/////////////////////////////////////");
            }
        }

        private static StringsDiff Difference(string firststring, string secondstring)
        {
            StringsDiff _stringsDiff = new StringsDiff();
            char[] _firstStringArray = firststring.ToCharArray();
            char[] _secondStringArray = secondstring.ToCharArray();
            int lenght;
            
            if (_firstStringArray.Length > _secondStringArray.Length)
            {
                lenght = _secondStringArray.Length;
                
                for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                {
                    if (!_firstStringArray[i].Equals(_secondStringArray[i]))
                    {
                        _stringsDiff._diffList1.Add(_firstStringArray[i]);
                        _stringsDiff._diffList2.Add(_secondStringArray[i]);
                    }
                }



                for (int i = _secondStringArray.Length; i < _firstStringArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    _stringsDiff._diffList1.Add(_firstStringArray[i]);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                lenght = _firstStringArray.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
                {
                    if (!_firstStringArray[i].Equals(_secondStringArray[i]))
                    {
                        _stringsDiff._diffList1.Add(_firstStringArray[i]);
                        _stringsDiff._diffList2.Add(_secondStringArray[i]);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = _firstStringArray.Length; i < _secondStringArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    _stringsDiff._diffList2.Add(_secondStringArray[i]);
                }
            }

            return _stringsDiff;
        }

        class StringsDiff
        {
            public List<char> _diffList1 = new List<char>();
            public List<char> _diffList2 = new List<char>();
        }
    }
```

Remember to use "string.join" to connect the lists objects if you need a string.

Comment: Thanks for this anwer. I implemented your code and it works correctly in the cases I tested it with. However, I noticed that the inner piece of code is used twice. This can be brought out of the if-else statement.

Comment: Happy the code worked for you! the different is on which string lenght you are using for the loop, you want to use the shorter string lenght to loop with so you wont get an  out of range exception.

Answer (score 1):

@ngdeveloper. This is my variant of your solution (had to post it in a separate answer because of the length):

```
private static StringsDiff Difference(string firststring, string secondstring)
{
    StringsDiff _stringsDiff = new StringsDiff();
    char[] _firstStringArray = firststring.ToCharArray();
    char[] _secondStringArray = secondstring.ToCharArray();
    int shortestLenght;
    int longestLenght;
    bool firstIsLongest;

    if (_firstStringArray.Length > _secondStringArray.Length)
    {
        firstIsLongest = true;
        shortestLenght = _secondStringArray.Length;
        longestLenght = _firstStringArray.Length;
    }
    else
    {
        firstIsLongest = false;
        shortestLenght = _firstStringArray.Length;
        longestLenght = _secondStringArray.Length;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < shortestLenght; i++)
    {
        if (!_firstStringArray[i].Equals(_secondStringArray[i]))
        {
            _stringsDiff._diffList1.Add(_firstStringArray[i]);
            _stringsDiff._diffList2.Add(_secondStringArray[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = shortestLenght; i < longestLenght; i++)
    {
        if (firstIsLongest)
            _stringsDiff._diffList1.Add(_firstStringArray[i]);
        else
            _stringsDiff._diffList2.Add(_secondStringArray[i]);
    }
    return _stringsDiff;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'm not using c# a lot this days but it is always fun to write this kind of methods!

Comment: it doesn't really work well; they will output both strings from the first diff char to the end.

Comment: @ender what were the test strings and which .net version did you use?